# Is there a nonblocking connect() for tcp stream?

Tags: rust

It is noticed that `std::net::TcpStream.set_nonblocking()` just make read/write/recv/send nonblocking here:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.set_nonblocking

But my question is how to make connect() nonblocking?

Comment: I'm not wake up this morning, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.connect_timeout

Comment: @Stargateur , thank you very much. connect_timeout() is used to set max duration for waiting. But here I need a function to abort connect anytime. For example, to response the user click of Cancel button.

Comment: that require more feature that what offer std, I advice you look at https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial, but note that it's by far one of the hardest thing in prog AND in rust

Comment: @Stargateur thanks, I'm now using mio as nonblock socket.